# how to install cudnn5.1 with cuda 8.0 support for tensorflow?

Tags: cuda, tensorflow, cudnn

I am unable to find the cudnn-8.0-linux-x64-v5.1.tgz file. The download link has only .deb file and when I install it using 
    sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file
I get libcudnn.so.5.1.5 file and not the headers (cudnn.h). Where can I get the .tgz file with all the .so and .h files? I am looking for libcudnn.so.5.1

Answer (score 1):

You can download cuDNN from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn), you need to have an NVIDIA developer account which is free of cost. After downloading it, extract the contents and copy the files to appropriate locations:

```
$ sudo cp -P include/cudnn.h /usr/include
$ sudo cp -P lib64/libcudnn* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
$ sudo chmod a+r /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn*
```